# Highlight part of a string in a cell content based on a filter value

Tags: r, shiny, dt

As the next step to the example provided in http://rstudio.github.io/DT/010-style.html I wish to highlight a part of a string in a cell based on a filter value as shown in the image below. I am trying to highlight specific motifs in  biological sequence data in table format. Given below is the Excel VBA code and a representative image. Is it possible to achieve this in R?

```
Sub SequencePartColourMacro()
Dim Col, Row, FirstRow, LastRow As Integer, Col As Long

Col = 6
FirstRow = 2
LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sequences").Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

Test1 = "CC"
Test2 = "TT"
Test3 = "GG"

For Row = FirstRow To LastRow
   Sequence = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sequences").Cells(Row, Col).Value
   For x = 1 To Len(Sequence)
     SubSequence1 = Mid(Sequence, x, 2)
     If SubSequence1 = Test1 Then
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sequences").Cells(Row, Col).Characters(x, 2).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sequences").Cells(Row, Col).Characters(x, 2).Font.Bold = True
     End If
    If SubSequence1 = Test2 Then
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sequences").Cells(Row, Col).Characters(x, 2).Font.Color = RGB(0, 102, 0)
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sequences").Cells(Row, Col).Characters(x, 2).Font.Bold = True
    End If
    If SubSequence1 = Test3 Then
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sequences").Cells(Row, Col).Characters(x, 2).Font.Color = RGB(255, 153, 0)
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sequences").Cells(Row, Col).Characters(x, 2).Font.Bold = True
    End If
 Next x
 Next Row
 End Sub
```

[image: Representative image showing highlighted characters]

Comment: So when you say filter value you are not talking about the actual filter search box of the table. You have predetermined strings test1, test2, test3 that you want highlighted in the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a little verbose, but so is VBA in general:

```
library(DT)
set.seed(1986)
x <- vector()
# create fake dna or rna sequence (it's been a while since I took bio)
for (i in 1:10) {
  x[i] <- paste0(sample(c("A","G","T","C"),10,replace=TRUE), collapse="")
}

dim(x) <- c(5,2)

datatable(x, options = list(rowCallback=JS(
  "function(row,data) {
    data[0]=data[0].replace('CC','<span style=\"color:red\">CC</span>');
    data[0]=data[0].replace('TT','<span style=\"color:blue\">TT</span>');
    data[0]=data[0].replace('GG','<span style=\"color:green\">GG</span>');
    data[1]=data[1].replace('CC','<span style=\"color:red\">CC</span>');
    data[1]=data[1].replace('TT','<span style=\"color:blue\">TT</span>');
    data[1]=data[1].replace('GG','<span style=\"color:green\">GG</span>');
    $('td:eq(0)', row).html(data[0]);
    $('td:eq(1)', row).html(data[1]);
  }"
  ), dom = 't'))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Carl. However, my situation is, the search terms/motifs like "TAG"   and few other will be hard coded or provided in a multiple select filter, and each search term/motif has to be highlighted in different fg color (or different fg and bg color). This was a trivial trick in Excel-VBA but couldn't implement in R.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean can you please edit your question and include an example with VBA

Comment: Great! @Carl, You Made my day.

Comment: How to make the second occurrence and more occurrences of the characters like "TT" in the first row of the  V1 column also highlight?

Answer (score 2):

Little tweaking of @Carl's code results in identifying and highlighting all occurrences of a chosen string. May be useful to someone like me.

```
library(DT)
set.seed(1986)
x <- vector()
 create fake dna or rna sequence (it's been a while since I took bio)
for (i in 1:10) {
 x[i] <- paste0(sample(c("A","G","T","C"),25,replace=TRUE), collapse="")
}
dim(x) <- c(5,2)

datatable(x, options = list(rowCallback=JS(
  "function(row,data) {
  data[0] = data[0]  .replace(/GA/g,'<span style=\"color:red\">GA</span>');
  data[0] = data[0]  .replace(/TT/g,'<span style=\"color:blue\">TT</span>');
  data[0] = data[0]  .replace(/TC/g,'<span style=\"color:green\">TC</span>');
  data[1] = data[1]  .replace(/GA/g,'<span style=\"color:red\">GA</span>');
  data[1] = data[1]  .replace(/TT/g,'<span style=\"color:blue\">TT</span>');
  data[1] = data[1]  .replace(/TC/g,'<span style=\"color:green\">TC</span>');
  $('td:eq(0)', row).html(data[0]  );
  $('td:eq(1)', row).html(data[1]  );
  }"
  ), dom = 't'))
```