# How to highlight bunch of adjacent cells in a row containing single character per cell based on a pattern in R Shiny DT

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, dt

This query is an extension to my earlier [query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40621174/highlight-part-of-a-string-in-a-cell-content-based-on-a-filter-value) in this forum. But, this time I have to process a sequence of characters in a row with each character in a cell as shown below in the image. I want to highlight or change background of certain cells based on a pattern like:

1. any adjacent cells containing letters like `A?C` where `?` could be any letter or
2. just `M` in a cell or
3. N and F in adjacent cells like `NF` as shown below in the images.

**In other words, need to convert this table to**
[image: Series of letters in adjacent column cells]

**this using rowCallback function in R Shiny DT.**
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am pimping my package here, so this may not be ok for you as it just uses an HTML table not a DT, and works on the R side not in javascript.

```
find_pattern <- function (pat, mat) {
  # collapse the row into a single string:
  strings <- apply(mat, 1, paste0, collapse = '')
  # find the patterns you want:
  found   <- gregexpr(pat, strings, perl = TRUE)
  # the rest is just housekeeping:
  pos <- matrix(FALSE, nrow(mat), ncol(mat))
  lapply(seq_along(found), function (x) {
    matches <- found[[x]]
    lens <- attr(matches, 'match.length')
    if (all(matches == -1)) return()
    for (p in seq_along(matches)) {
      start <- matches[p]
      len <- lens[p]
      end <- start + len - 1
      pos[x, start:end] <<- TRUE 
    }
  })
  which(pos, arr.ind = TRUE)
}

library(huxtable)
mydata <- matrix(sample(c('A', 'B', 'C', 'M', 'N', 'F'), 750, replace=TRUE), 3, 250)
colnames(mydata) <- paste0('X', 1:250)
myhux <- as_hux(mydata, add_colnames = TRUE)
myhux <- set_all_borders(myhux, 1)
background_color(myhux)[1,] <- 'grey'
background_color(myhux)[myhux == 'M'] <- 'green'
background_color(myhux)[find_pattern('A.C', myhux)] <- 'yellow'
background_color(myhux)[find_pattern('NF', myhux)] <- 'blue'
myhux
```

Which results in:

[image]

The `find_pattern` function will accept any perl regular expression you throw at it. `A.C` means, A, followed by any letter, followed by C.

Comment: I very much appreciate your effort. However, I was looking to highlight a pattern in the row of letters. Highlighting specific individual letters is straight forward. But looking for a pattern and highlighting a bunch of cells matching the pattern is challenging. I could almost accomplish this in Excel VBA. I am trying to implement the same in R Shiny DT.

Comment: I'll edit my answer to do what you need more precisely -  it still won't be a data table answer, but it might give you a hint.

Comment: It need not be a datatable answer. As long as I am able to generate a table highlighting specific patterns in a row of cells, I am good.

Comment: The above answer looks promising. I will try to implement this and get back to you. Great effort!